# If a paper has been accepted at a conference does it mean that it will be published?

Tags: conference, research-undergraduate, publishability

I have a paper that has been accepted at the International Conference on Advanced Computational and Communication Paradigms (ICACCP).

Comment: Ask them. They are the only authoritative source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the conference website:

> All accepted and presented papers will be submitted to IEEE Xplore (Digital Library) for conference proceedings publication and will be submitted to Scopus for possible indexing, IEEE Conference Record #45516. IEEE Xplore ISBN: 978-1-5386-7989-0.

Note that you are required to actually *attend* the conference and *give a presentation* (and pay the registration fee). With any conference, if you submit a paper which is subsequently accepted, you are expected to attend the conference and present the paper. If you do not attend the conference (barring exceptional circumstances which you communicate to the organizing committee), then the paper might not be included in the proceedings (i.e., will not be published).

Note that computer science is a bit of an outlier because it considers conference papers as publications. Many other fields do not consider conference publications as "real" publications as the review process tends to be less thorough. Many papers (even in computer science) which start out as conference publications are later published (in a more polished, expanded form) as journal publications.

Answer (score 2):

[Their website](http://www.icaccpa.in/) suggests so but, as Buffy writes in the comments, the only real way to tell is by asking them.

[image]